# GWT: is it possible to check parent size BEFORE adding next child but AFTER CSS rules are applied to that child?

Tags: java, gwt, resize

Imagine we have some parent container. We add children to it, one by one. Children widgets are placed according to some CSS: may be as block elements, may be as inline elements.

A question is:
Can we calculate the supposed parent height and width BEFORE adding next child and manage to insert "SHOW MORE" widget instead of adding next child?

I tried to add ResizeEvent handler to my container. It catches the event, but only at the very moment when child widget is added, but CSS rules are not applied yet! That means that ResizeEvent is caught when all the children widgets are placed one on top of another as block elements, but in fact they should be placed as inline elements. After ResizeEvent Handler runs CSS rules are applied and child-widgets are reordered as inline elements, but this is not causing new ResizeEvents to parent container, which height is small again..

So in fact I want to catch the moment of resizing of my parent container before it happens.. a kind of a "if you add this child - parent needs resize" or "if you add this child - parent size is bigger than ... px" trigger.

So is it possible to solve this task?

Comment: Does your child blocks contain some images?

Comment: Maksym, they can, but probably I can add image tag after the calculations, if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found a solution which is good for me:

I create a container with fixed size and an internal container which can spread inside it. The overflow of the top container is hidden. Thus, when I add next widget that cannot be displayed because it is out of the bounds of my top container - well, it is not displayed.. just because overflow is hidden. 
The only thing that remains is to insert a "SHOW MORE" widget. To do it I calculate whether the last inserted widget bounds are out of the bounds of top container. I.e. whether the last inserted widget overflows top container, or not. If yes, I insert "SHOW MORE" widget in place if previous (the one before last) widget.

Thats it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the browser to render the new widget before you measure its height:

```
// add widget to the container
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
@Override
public void execute() {
        // measure it here
});
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei, but this means the widget will be shown?

Comment: You simply have to wait until the browser finishes rendering one widget before you decide if you want to add another one. It usually takes milliseconds, but if you don't wait, you get 0 instead of a real height.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using following technique:

- Make a copy of your parent container. Attach it to the DOM somewhere. Make it invisible for users using some CSS tricks (z-index, margin-left: 10000px, ....) **but do not use display:none**.
- Attach your child to this "invisible" parent first. Override `Window.onAttach()` for child. Calculate height and width.
- Take a decision about what to insert into real parent (this child or "show more" link).
- Move your child widget from invisible parent to real parent if necessary.

Hope there is another more simple way to do it.

Calculated height and width will be wrong if your child contain some images, because `Window.onAttach()` is called **before** the moment when all images are loaded.